# Set complex type to null in ADF Data flow and omit it

Tags: azure-data-factory, derived-column

Sink seems to omit automatically all primitive types, if they are null, I need the same for a complex type objects, when all their attributes are null, because currently I end up with state "complexType": {} , so I need to omit that empty object somehow.

In a Derived Column I tried using an expression like:

```
iif(!isNull(complexType.field) && !isNull(complexType.field1) && !isNull(complexType.field2),
complexType, null)
```

but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: What does `seems to omit automatically` mean? Share with some data and explain the requirement.

Comment: The requirement is that if all attributes of a complex type are null, then the complex type should not be shown in the json at all, and currently I get an empty object ("complexType": {} ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Expression should return the same type 'null' as previous expressions.

The above error occurs in ADF dataflow, when expressions in `iif` are of different types. If one expression is of complex type and other is of null type, it is not possible to update the value. Also, you cannot convert the null value to complex datatype. Only way to replace `{}` empty object is to convert the expressions in iif to string type. Below is the correct expression.

```
iif(isNull(complexfield.field1)&&isNull(complexfield.field2),toString(null()),toString(complexfield))
```

This expression checks if the  `field1`  and  `field2`  fields of the  `complexfield`  object are null, and if they are, it returns a null value using  `toString(null())`. If the fields are not null, it returns the  `complexfield`  object as a string using  `toString(complexfield)`.

Comment: Seems feasible, still, I need to convert the newly created string back to the initial complex object type, which adds another level of complexity, I hoped there is a more straight-forward way of doing this.

Comment: empty object cannot be null while all other data will be of complex type. That is the reason for the above fallback answer.